# Fetching global values from database on application startup in Spring boot

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

I'm writing a Spring Boot / JPA application. I have some values which needs to be visible to the entire application and these values are located in a database. Where should I fetch these values? Should I fetch them in the class containing `@SpringBootApplication`?

And how do I make it visible to the application? I read that with Spring, we can use a `@Bean` class to hold global variables. Then do I have to map my `@Entity` class with a Bean class and autowire the Bean class where ever I want? I'm new to Spring / JPA, so I apologize if the question is basic.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you want to happen if values in the database change?

Comment: For now, I can work with stale data. But eventually, it should get updated when the values in the DB changes. How should I handle the different scenarios?

Comment: Any suggestions / ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Make a bean that is instantiated with your applicationContext, and use the init-method to run some code after it's instantiated.

A very off the top of my head solution:

In applicationContext.xml:

`<bean class="com.example.DbConfigLoader" init-method="init">`

A class to load a config entity at startup:

```
public class DbConfigLoader {

    @Autowired
    private DbConfigRepository repository;

    private DbConfig dbConfig;

    public void init(){
        dbConfig = repository.findOne(1L);
    }

    public DbConfig getDbConfig() {
        return dbConfig;
    }
}
```

A class representing your config:

```
@Entity
public class DbConfig {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    private String someSetting;

    public String getSomeSetting() {
        return someSetting;
    }
}
```

A Spring Data repository for easy database access:

```
public interface DbConfigRepository extends JpaRepository<DbConfig, Long> {
}
```